# Why won't C# accept a (seemingly) perfectly good Sql Server CE Query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

By perfectly good sql query, I mean to say that, inside WebMatrix, if I execute the following query, it works to perfection:

```
SELECT page AS location, (len(page) - len(replace(UPPER(page), UPPER('o'), ''))) / len('o') AS occurences, 'pageSettings' AS tableName FROM PageSettings WHERE page LIKE '%o%'
UNION
SELECT pageTitle AS location, (len(pageTitle) - len(replace(UPPER(pageTitle), UPPER('o'), ''))) / len('o') AS occurences, 'ExternalSecondaryPages' AS tableName FROM ExternalSecondaryPages WHERE pageTitle LIKE '%o%' 
UNION
SELECT eventTitle AS location, (len(eventTitle) - len(replace(UPPER(eventTitle), UPPER('o'), ''))) / len('o') AS occurences, 'MainStreetEvents' AS tableName FROM MainStreetEvents WHERE eventTitle LIKE '%o%'
```

Here i am using `'o'` as a static search string to search upon. No problem, but not exeactly very dynamic.

Now, when I write this query as a string in C# and as I think it should be (and even as I have done before) I get a server-side error indicating that the string was not in the correct format.  Here is a pic of that error:

[image]

And (although I am only testing the output, should I get it to quit erring), here is the actual C# (i.e., the `.cshtml`) page that queries the database:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Layouts/_secondaryMainLayout.cshtml";    

    var db = Database.Open("Content");
    string searchText = Request.Unvalidated["searchText"];
    string selectQueryString = "SELECT page AS location, (len(page) - len(replace(UPPER(page), UPPER(@0), ''))) / len(@0) AS occurences, 'pageSettings' AS tableName FROM PageSettings WHERE page LIKE '%' + @0 + '%' ";
    selectQueryString += "UNION ";
    selectQueryString += "SELECT pageTitle AS location, (len(pageTitle) - len(replace(UPPER(pageTitle), UPPER(@0), ''))) / len(@0) AS occurences, 'ExternalSecondaryPages' AS tableName FROM ExternalSecondaryPages WHERE pageTitle LIKE '%' + @0 + '%' ";
    selectQueryString += "UNION ";
    selectQueryString += "SELECT eventTitle AS location, (len(eventTitle) - len(replace(UPPER(eventTitle), UPPER(@0), ''))) / len(@0) AS occurences, 'MainStreetEvents' AS tableName FROM MainStreetEvents WHERE eventTitle LIKE '%' + @0 + '%'";

    @:beginning <br/>
    foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString, searchText))
    {
        @:entry
        @:@row.location &nbsp;
        @:@row.occurences &nbsp;
        @:@row.tableName
        <br/>
    }
}
```

Since it is erring on the `foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString, searchText))` line, that heavily suggests that something is wrong with my query, however, everything seems right to me about the syntax here and it even executes to perfection if I query the database (mind you, un-parameterized) directly.

Logically, I would assume that I have erred somewhere with the syntax involved in parameterizing this query, however, my double and triple checking (as well as, my past experience at doing this) *insists* that everything looks fine here.

Have I messed up the syntax involved with parameterizing this query, or is something else at play here that I am overlooking?

I know I can tell you, for sure, as it has been previously tested, that the value I am getting from the query string is, indeed, what I would expect it to be, but as there really isn't much else on the `.cshtml` page yet, that is about all I can tell you.

Comment: Usually this error would occur if your parameter object type passed into `.Query()` doesn't match what would be expected by the SQL @0 variables.  In this case, I'm wondering if it's valid to specify the same parameter in more than one place in a query string.

Comment: Is it because there is a 0 rather than an o? just a punt really

Comment: @ebyrob Actually, that is legal, as I have used it before (and thank goodness it is). But standby, I think I have actually found the problem. Will post in one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *would* find the answer to my 2-day long search for a solution to this problem, just after posting a question here, but alas, when looking a little closer at some old code I used, I found that in the `LIKE` phrase I actually used `CAST` such that, if used in the LIKE phrase in my above example, it would look like this:

```
LIKE '%' + CAST(@0 AS nvarchar) + '%'
```

I suppose a regular C# string isn't the same thing as a sql `nvarchar` data type.

There's still an accept and upvote in it for anyone who can possibly shed a little more light on this for anyone (including myself) that may benefit from a more precise explanation (that is, if there is anything more to it than a simple "it's just not the same data type" explanation).

(NOTE: If it helps any future viewer to know, the parameters in the LIKE phrase is *ALL* that I changed. I did not have to cast or change anything about the syntax involved in the parameters written outside of the LIKE phrases).

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but may shed some light.  Try executing the following query and read the results:

```
select top 1 sql_variant_property(@0, 'BaseType') as type from MainStreetEvents;
```

For any passed object parameter that doesn't error out, you should get back information about what sql type is being used to represent it.

Comment: This is a very good idea, but it seems that SQL Server CE doesn't recognize `sql_variant_property`. Again, though it is a good idea for testing.

Comment: @VoidKing shoot.  The only other thing I can think of is running an unencrypted tcp connection to the server and sniffing the connection to see what the raw commands going to SQL Server look like.  (probably all local in your setup though right?  Why else run SQL CE?)

Comment: Well, actually, while in development it is totally local, I continually have to update what I've designed so far on a server environment so that I can test how the site looks (and behaves) on 32-bit machines (i.e., the 32-bit browsers *on* the machines). What would you use to sniff the tcp packets, something like WireShark? Am I thinking of the right kind of program?

Comment: @VoidKing Yep wireshark... but the trick is to use a SQL driver/connection string that isn't hard to read (though wireshark may have dissectors for some SQL stuff)

Comment: Many thanks, I will look that over. And, very smart approach to finding the truth behind the difference between a C# string and sql-server-CE's nvarchar data type, btw.